# Angular 5: get the value of node from component selector

Tags: angular

How can I get the text content from the component selector?

As an example:

```
<div class="page-wrapper">
    <app-page-title>List applications</app-page-title>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

I have the `app-page-title` component, but I do not understand, how I can get the value of this node ("List applications") in my component.

**UPD:**

```
<app-card>
  <app-card-title>Some My Title</app-card-title>
  <app-card-content>Some My Content</app-card-content>
  <app-card-footer>Some My Footer</app-card-footer>
</app-card>
```

How can I get the inner nodes from `app-card` component?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it, would be to set the title in your component and then interpolate that into your view. For instance.

```
<div class="page-wrapper">
    <app-page-title>{{myPageTitle}}</app-page-title>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

And then in your component typescript, it would be something like:

```
@Component({...})
export class pageTitleComponent {
  ...
  myPageTitle = 'List applications'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to rewrite it like this:

```
<div class="page-wrapper">
    <app-page-title text="List applications"></app-page-title>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

If so, then you can define an input property in the app-page-title (child) component using the input decorator. Then the child component has the value in that property.

```
@Input() text: string;
```